# Error Submit App iOS Cordova CFBundle: icon.png

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, itunes

I'm trying to send an application developed using the cord in xcode 7 and are experiencing this error.

[image: Errror]

I've looked on google hours a solution of this case, but all told it did not work ... Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: check what is the path mentioned in info.plist for the icon files key.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the value for icon file in Info.plist file in xcode, which is under Resources folder. If you cant find it you can look it for by clicking the search icon at top left side of xcode.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug on cordova ios, but it has been fixed on cordova ios 4.1.0

Update your project with

```
cordova platform add ios@4.1.0
```

If you can't update, then open the Info.plist file on `projectName/platforms/ios/projectName/` and remove this:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>icon.png</string>
```